# MongoDB atlas connection not working from within a docker container running ASP.net core. Works fine from inside kestrel

Tags: asp.net, .net, mongodb, .net-core

We have asp.net core based docker containers trying to connect to MongoDB atlas with the C# driver version 2.4.3.

The connection is working fine for when we run it outside the container. i.e. directly from kestrel. But when the same code is run from within a container, the connection to mongodb atlas times out.

**Details:**
MongoDB C# Driver version: 2.4.3

Connection String:
mongodb://sa:@cluster0-shard-00-00-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017/admin?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin

Database to be accessed: Configurations

ASP.net Core version: 1.1

BaseImage in Dockerfile: microsoft/aspnetcore-build

Dockerfile contents:
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build
WORKDIR /SaaS_Configuration_Microservice
COPY ./SaaS_Configuration_Microservice .
EXPOSE 80
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o PublishOutput
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PublishOutput/SaaS_Configuration_Microservice.dll"]

We are running kestrel in Windows 10.

**Complete Error Message:**
        ex.Message  "A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : \"1\", ConnectionMode : \"ReplicaSet\", Type : \"ReplicaSet\", State : \"Disconnected\", Servers : [{ ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command failed.\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__11.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.<InitializeConnectionAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.<OpenHelperAsync>d__48.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.<HeartbeatAsync>d__27.MoveNext()\" }, { ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-01-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-01-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command failed.\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.d__11.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__3.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()\" }, { ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-02-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-02-po5vp.mongodb.net:27017\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command failed.\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.ProcessReply(ConnectionId connectionId, ReplyMessage`1 reply)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandWireProtocol`1.d__11.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.d__3.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__48.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.d__27.MoveNext()\" }] }."   string

Inner exception: null

Comment: Ping to google and https://cloud.mongodb.com/ is working fine from inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

"microsoft/aspnetcore-build" is a Linux image and there is a bug:
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#c-net-driver-example

> IMPORTANT The .NET Core library does not support the SNI TLS extension
>   on Linux and OSX. Applications using .NET Core on these operating
>   systems cannot connect to a Atlas Free Tier cluster.
>
> The issue is tracked on the [dotnet/corefx github page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9608).

Comment: To clarify; this is assuming that you're using the Atlas Free Tier. If you're not, then it may be another issue altogether.

Comment: SNI support is already implemented in .NET Core 2.1 preview: github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17427 and with this patch MongoDb Driver works fine.